# Windows Snmp Management Api - Snmp timeout/retry doesn't appear to work

Tags: snmp

I'm noticing some weird snmp communication behavior when using MS SNMP Mgmt Api in terms of timeout and retries. I was wondering if mgmt api is supported on Win Server 2008 R1 x64. My program is a C++ 64bit snmp extension agent that uses the mgmt api to communicate with other agents as well.

This is my pseudo code:

```
SnmpMgrOpen(ip address, 150ms timeout, 3 retries)
start = getTickCount()
result = SnmpMgrRequest(get request with 3 or 4 OIDs)
finish = getTickCount()
if (result == some error)
{
     log Error including total time (i.e finish - start ticks)
}
SnmpMgrClose()
```

When the snmpMgrRequest call times out, the total time equals anywhere from 1014ms to 5000ms. If, I set retries to 0, the total time is still 1014ms to 5000ms.

I would expect, with retries to 0 that the SnmpMgrRequest would timeout within 150ms. The documentation seems to imply this. Am I missing something is there a minimum timeout period of at least a second? What could be causing this behavior?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm at a lost here.

ballerstyle_98@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with SNMP on Windows platforms the minimum timeout value is 1 second. So even if you set it to any value lower than that, it will default to 1 second.

Also the timeout value used is doubled for every retry. So with a 150ms 3 retry configuration in the worst case you will have a failed response to a request in  1+2+2+2 =7 seconds.

I hope this helps.